# look_down that checks (inside HTML) content

Tags: perl

With `HTML::TreeBuilder`, using command  `$root->look_down(_tag => 'a')`  I get **first** anchor.

(1) How can I find **last** anchor?

Additionally, how can I check for inside content of the tag, to check if it does or does not contain some string inside of it? So for example,

(2) how can I find an anchor that contains *"Hallo"* or *"hallo"* in inside HTML?

(3) how can I find an anchor that **DOES NOT** contain *"Hallo"* or *"hallo"* in inside HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `look_down()` function returns a list of all `<a>` tags found, so simply access to last element of it using an index, like:

```
my $last_a_tag = ($root->look_down(_tag => 'a'))[-1]
```

To search into its text, use `content_list()` function, that returns a list with all child text elements. Then use a `map()` function to check if it contains or not any text, like:

```
map { m/[Hh]allo/ } $last_a_tag->content_list;
```